# Gradle failed to build on a new hardware using the same installation method

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

After I copy my project to a new laptop, I tried to run a flutter project in vscode. however during debugging gradle failed to build and gave me this in the debug console

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
> lib\main.dart:1
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\PROJECT_NAME\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Folder.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\ea4ydi90mwjg9g63m7r6nimmx).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
> Exited (sigterm)

I have no idea what went wrong since the JDK is the same version (19) as my old laptop

edit: I tried to download a new gradle, and create a new empty project, and I still get the same error

Running a flutter project on the new laptop

Comment: looks like you updated android studio...

Comment: Try cleaning the Gradle cache on your new laptop using this command:   

    ./gradlew clean

Comment: somehow .gradlew command and gradle didn't work, it didn't get recognized. this is quite weird since I follow the installation guide I used before